# Designing without AutoLayout and Size Classes yet simulator still different than actual device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, size

I decided not to use size classes and autolayout because of how annoying they are, so instead I designed for the largest screen (5.5 inch) and then have a separate storyboard for every other screen.

Now, I designed the view in storyboard and everything looks fine. I tested it out in the iPhone 6S Plus simulator and everything looks perfect. But when I test on a physical iPhone 6S Plus device, images are being cutoff and it isn't scaling like it should.

I don't understand how this is even possible?

Simulator (iPhone 6S Plus) and Storyboard:

[image]

Physical Device (iPhone 6S Plus):

[image]

Comment: First of all if you are not using autolayout than you are doing 3 to 4 times more work than you should if u cannot understand autolayout spend more time on it.

Comment: I accept working 3 to 4 times harder, because AutoLayout has been a real pain in the butt. I tried my best to work with it, I just can't get it to work well with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Check out these links https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints

Comment: Already been through them, didn't help. Trust me, I have tried my best to work with AutoLayout, it just doesn't like to cooperate. I will like to know though why though, with it off, that the simulator and the physical device do not match?

Comment: I could not find any tutorials as they are quite old.So you disabled autolayout than you are using auto resizing here is a link to see how it works play around it maybe you understand what you did wrong https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3yb24f8O1Y

Comment: Thanks it is working for the most work. But I still don't understand why the simulator and the physical device are not the same. Why is this happening?

Comment: @Cyogenos I'm having this exact same issue with the 6+ (And I am using auto layout for the view, but still getting this issue).   For me, a UILabel on a TableView is looking & fitting fine on the 6+ in the simulator, but it is getting cut off when displayed on the real device, even after tweaking layout.   Did you ever find any resolution to this issue?